# Any best practices to record high quality images in rosbag?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, rosbag, asus

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to record images (RGB+depth) into a rosbag using ASUS Xtion Pro Live. I followed [this](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/openni_launch%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29BagRecordingPlayback.html) tutorial on what topics to record. But it did not mention anything about the quality aspect. For example does rosbag has options (like ffmpeg) to record the images/video as high or low quality? Or is it the openni_camera or openni_launch that takes care of this aspect? For example ASUS has depth resolution 640×480 @ 30 fps, 320×240 @ 60 fps and color 1280×1024 @ 30 fps. How do I select the quality options in ROS?

Thanks in advance,
Krish

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89811/any-best-practices-to-record-high-quality-images-in-rosbag?/) by [Krishna Dubba](https://answers.ros.org/users/2103/krishna-dubba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag will store the raw messages however they arrive and knows nothing specific about images or any other data type.

So, what you send in your sender will determine the quality of images that are stored.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4